# Numbers 3 - How to apply custom chart style

Tags: macos, numbers, iwork

Using Numbers 3.0 with Mavericks.

I am creating a bunch of scatter plots in numbers. I want to remove the big bubbly data point symbols and simply display the data as connected points.

Setting this up is no problem for one chart. I'd like to apply this style to every chart I make for the remainder of my project.

When I select the chart, I see a bunch of different chart icons in the 'chart styles' section of the formatting bar. I can apparently add the style of my current chart to this group for future use by clicking on a blank square with a plus button next to it. When I click the plus button, a new icon shows up in that little box.

Apple describes this process [here.](http://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/3.0/#/tand2682bcee)

I assume that, if I create another chart, I should be able to just click on that last custom chart style I had 'saved' and the series formatting would automatically change. But alas, it doesn't.

Is there something I'm missing? Does the "chart style" only allow changing the colors of the different series on a  graph, as opposed to accounting for changed data point styling?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Data Symbols series preference is not a part of the styles. Why can't you select all of the charts when you are finished with them (by Command clicking or Command + Shift dragging) and then changing the data point styling of all of them at one time?